# Toolkit for NodeXl in Java

Tags: java, twitter, graph, toolkit, gephi

Is there any tool to NodeXL (or any program that has a similar functionality, so allowing import graphs from Twitter) that you can use from Java?

I'm currently using Gephi toolkit in a Java application but only allows me to import graphs from my pc, and I want the application allows me to get the graphs directly from twitter.

For that, I am looking for a toolkit that allows me download graphs from Twitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing I have used. You could have a look [here](http://en.paradigmatecnologico.com/blog/retweet-monitor-plugin-for-gephi/) and [here](http://guidogarcia.net/blog/2012/01/21/graph-yourtwitter-network-with-gephi/). The second one provides a link to a GitHub repository with to communicate with Twitter through its API